# WebGL: getUniformLocation fails on Safari

Tags: safari, webgl2

I get the error `Uniform A not found` when I try to get Uniform A's location in Safari (with WebGL 2 enabled).

This code runs with no issues on Chrome/MacOS and on all browsers in Windows.

Here's the fragment shader:

```
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
varying vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D A;

float indentity_(float a) {
  return a;
}
vec4 indentity_(vec4 v) {
  return v;
}

void main() {
  vec4 v = texture2D(A, TexCoords);
  v = indentity_(v);
  gl_FragColor = v;
}
```

This is the Safari version:

```
Safari 12.0.1 (Mac OS X 10.14.1)
```

I get the webgl context using 'webgl2'. Not sure if that's the right way to do it for Safari or not.

thanks

Comment: I saw your other questions, i think as user Gman already pointed out, you are pretty much on your own digging into this. Also hard to say, what is really going on, w/out seeing the full code, the the error could be somewhere else. From this far away, texture2D() called in WebGL2.0 with just texture(). I'm not a Mac OS/Safari user, so what i can say is: Stick with the official examples, and from their file a Bug-report on Webkit website.
https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/tree/master/LayoutTests/fast/canvas/webgl/webgl2

Comment: oh and yes, this is actually no a valid shader version 300 es syntax. look here
https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl1-to-webgl2.html

Comment: thanks for weighing in Nabr

Comment: Safari has **never** supported WebGL2. If you look into the webkit source no code to support WebGL2 has been added and there as been no activity in over 2 years. [Here's the conformance tests for WebGL2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/webgl-conformance-tests.html?version=2.0.1). Search on the page for "conformance2" and run any test. They all fail. It's pretty likely that Safari will never support WebGL2. Apple seems to be concentrating on WebGPU but it's probably at least a year, maybe 2 years away from shipping

Comment: There's an option to enable it using the Develop menu item then selecting Experimental features. But thanks for the additional investigation @gman

Comment: Yes, Apple added an "enable WebGL2" option to Safari but never actually implemented any of it.

Comment: @JeffSaremi you understand that your question is almost unanswerable,just too much stuff is happening in the browser even before the load and validation of a shader. If you ever what some answer, progress. You need to put more work from your side and provide an example. like runs fine on firefox/chrome(latest) windows 10 OS --> https://jsfiddle.net/nabr/6byz9edo/